# Query orders table and get most recent record for each customer

Tags: mysql

I have a table of orders. Customers can appear multiple times. The orderID column is an auto increment. I need to run a query to get the most recent order for each customer BUT I need to get the orderID, orderDate and orderProduct of their latest order.

```
customer    orderID     orderDate       orderProduct
1           1           2015-01-01      shoes
1           2           2015-02-01      food
1           3           2015-03-01      drinks
2           4           2015-01-01      water
2           5           2015-04-01      beer
3           6           2015-01-01      pizza
3           7           2015-07-01      pasta
```

I had hoped to use:

```
select orders.*, max(orderDate) as latestOrder from orders group by customer
```

But this doesn't seem to give me what I need.

The results I am looking for would be:

```
customer    orderID     orderDate       orderProduct
1           3           2015-03-01      drinks
2           5           2015-04-01      beer
3           7           2015-07-01      pasta
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use some kind of self-join here

```
select t1.* from orders t1
inner join (
  select customer, max(orderDate) as latestOrder from orders  
  group by customer
) t2
where t1.customer = t2.customer AND t1.orderDate = t2.latestOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT customer,orderID,orderDate,orderProduct,
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY orderID desc)
   FROM tab
)
select * from tab where orderid in (
select  max(orderid) as maxorder from cte group by customer)
```

This should work with any RDBMS that supports CTEs. Heres a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3d0ba/11)